# Is there a way to override the print method in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, python-object

Pretty simple question - I have searched but not found an answer to this question.

It might be a bit silly to do this but I was curious if it is possible to hook into the `print(*arg, **kwarg)` function of python 3.X and override it / add `time.sleep(var)` at the end of the invoke.

Of course I could just def another method and wrap it with a `time.sleep(var)` but I was just curious how one would go about overriding the pre-built functions.

Comment: `orig_print = print; print = new_function` should work. But I hardly think it's recommended. You'd better ask yourself why you would ever need to do such a thing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you need. Do you want to override ``print`` in a function, a code block, a module or an entire application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to patch any function globally, e.g. for testing / debugging purposes, the safest way is to use [`unittest.mock.patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

```
def x():
    '''the code under test'''
    print('Hello, world!')

...
from unittest.mock import patch
orig_print = print

with patch('builtins.print') as m:
    def my_print(*args, **kwargs):
        orig_print('PATCHED:', *args, **kwargs)

    m.side_effect = my_print

    x()  # prints 'PATCHED: Hello, world!'

# prints 'Hello, world!', because the patch context is exited
# and the original function is restored: 
x()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this one liner

```
out = print
print = lambda *args, **kwargs: [time.sleep(1), out(*args, **kwargs)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, you could do something like:

```py
def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
    # Your new print function here
    pass

print = new_print
```

It's recommended that you save the old print function, and you'll need it if you want to use it inside your print function.
You could do so like so

```py
old_print = print
def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
    old_print(*args, **kwargs)

print = new_print
```

If you now want to add sleeping to that, you can do so by just putting it in the new function

```py
import time

old_print = print
def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
    old_print(*args, **kwargs)
    time.sleep(5)

print = new_print
```

Comment: I tried this, but in `old_print = print` I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment` (Python 3.4)

Comment: @abu try `import builtins` and then `old_print = builtins.print` instead (or just use import and use `builtins.print` rather than saving it to old_print as well)

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that it would work, here an example. It is definitely not recommended though as you know.

```
import sys
def new_print(msg):
    sys.stdout.write("I always add this text\n")
    sys.stdout.write(msg)

print = new_print

print("Test")
```

> I always add this text
>
> Test